# Android DrawableLeft icon on Button looks randomly disabled

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-button

I've got a button in an activity in an fragment which shows its icon grey/disabled. The text is white and the button itself is enabled:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8J5D.png)

The things confusing me are:

- it is not always like this, rotating back and forth shows it white sometimes
- touching it and swiping somewhere else to not call onclick makes it white

My button code in fragment (I've tried directly in activity):

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/list_refresh_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_refresh_white_24dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_refresh_white_24dp"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:onClick="refreshServers"
    android:text="@string/action_refresh"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

The only thing I find on Google are people trying to disable buttons. I want my icon always enabled (except when I disable the button).

edit: I set the visibility in MainActivity
`onCreate() { findViewById(R.id.list_refresh_btn).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); }`
I tried always visible and it didn't help.

Comment: I fixed it for now by setting button disabled in the xml and enabling it async after onCreate().